# What is the difference betwen handling an event and extending a class and overriding the related protect On... method?

Tags: .net, events, methods, protected

In the .NET `System.Windows` assembly, classes often define events and raise them throughout the lifetime of the object. For example, the `UIElement` class defines the `KeyUp` event, which is 'alias to the Keyboard.KeyUp event':

```
public event KeyEventHandler KeyUp;
```

However, it also declares the `protected OnKeyUp` method, that is called upon the event being fired:

```
protected virtual void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e);
```

There is a protected method for each event, as far as I can see. As these methods are protected, they can only be called from a class that is extending the `UIElement` class. Let's imagine that I have such an extending class.

My question is, given my class that extends the `UIElement` class, what is the difference between overriding the protected method and handling the relevant event? Is there a difference at all? Is there any benefit from using the protected methods over handling the events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functionally they're usually used in ways that are interchangeable. In theory, you can do slightly more in the `override` approach - you can suppress the event from raising to *external* callers, or modify what they see in terms of the parameters they receive (pretending that a *different* key was pressed, for example), but... most of the time you don't do that, so it is moot. There are also some minor changes in terms of the actual objects involved. When using `override`, you also have more guarantees over *when* your code happens (if there are multiple subscribers to the same event/object). But again: usually, they're *largely* interchangeable. It is perhaps more *common* to `override` when it is **the same object** raising and handling, rather than subscribing to events *on yourself*, but either would work.